# WinSCP: Mirror directory in the background

Tags: winscp

I am transferring a large volume of small files to my server. I have been using the Synchronize feature to mirror the files from my hhd to my server. However unlike when I start a new transfer I cannot find a way to upload the files in the background. This is a problem because I can have up to 9 background transfers at the same time, which vastly improves the speed of the transfers.

How can I use the Synchronize feature to mirror the files, uploading them in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinSCP does not support use of multiple connections for synchronization.

Though you can script this using [WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library):

- Use [`Session.CompareDirectories` method](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_comparedirectories) to find the list of files that need synchronization.
- And then you can transfer those files using multiple connections. You can start with this example: [Automating transfers in parallel connections over SFTP/FTP protocol](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_example_parallel_transfers).